# Spy on function calls within an Express route

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

**UPDATE**:

In order to focus in on the problem below I had changed the test to `test.only`. When I changed it back to run all the tests it worked perfectly.

---

In my express application I send a welcome mail to a user when they sign up.

I'm currently testing the route by requesting the endpoint with `supertest` but it seems that way I can't actually spy on functionality within the route, only make asserts on the output.

I use Jest as test framework, but I think the challenge is framework agnostic.

My route (simplified):

```
const sendmail = require('../sendmail');

router.post("/register", function(req, res) {
    // Some validation and DB work

    sendmail.welomeEmail();

    res.send({ success: true, message: 'Signed up succesfully' });
})
```

And my test:

```
test("it should send a welcome email", done => {
  const sendmail = require("../sendmail");
  const spy = jest.spyOn(sendmail, "welcomeEmail");

  return request(app)
    .post("/register")
    .send({
      // User data
    })
    .then(response => {
      expect(response.statusCode).toBe(200);
      expect(response.body.success).toBeTruthy();
      expect(response.body.message).toBe("Signed up succesfully");
      expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled(); // This doesn't get called
      done();
    });
});
```

When I do this exact test by creating a file that calls the method it works perfectly, so my guess is that it's because it does a `request` and not actually invoke the router method.

How would one solve a situation like this where I want to make sure the sendmail module is used within the route?

Comment: How is your express app made in the test?

Comment: At the top it is included by `const app = require("../server/app");` which exports an express instance (it's not actually launched with .listen) in there

Comment: I remeber having this issue as well. I seemed to fix it by creating an express app in the test, rather than importing it from your actual implementation, then importing the route you are testing and include it in the fake express app to use in supertest.

Comment: Interesting, I had used `test.only` so i could focus on fixing it. When i changed it back to `test` everything worked as expected. Curious ..

Comment: Amazing :D javascript at its finest

Comment: Haha, indeed =) Thanks for rubberducking with me.

Answer (score 0):

There is a missing "c". In the router you are calling `sendmail.welomeEmail();` instead of `sendmail.welcomeEmail();`